# Creating a Base64 Coder and Decoder tool (PHP)

Tags: php, base64

How are you? I have a website and I have some webmaster tools. I have a decoder and coder of PHP base64. The tools are from an external website…. I use a iframe. But is not professional. I am not a php profecional but I will like to have a tool like this on my website… I only need the form code and the php code to get out the uncode or code base64.
Some can help me with this?

Regards, alex

Comment: This question should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made this; and it works simply.

```
<?php
//this is a first-draft, untested
$encode = $_POST['encode'];
$decode = $_POST['decode'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Awesome Base64 Transcoder
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
To encode: <input type="text" name="encode" value="<?php echo base64_decode($decode);?>">
<input type="submit" value="Encode">
</form>
<br />
<form action="" method="POST">
To decode: <input type="text" name="decode" value="<?php echo base64_encode($encode);?>">
<input type="submit" value="Decode">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has base64 built in. Have fun :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php